# Evaluate the following limit: $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{\tan(\frac{1}{x})}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

[According to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%281%2Bx%29%29%5Etan%281%2Fx%29%20as%20x-%3E0), this limit evaluates to 1.

However, I don't know how to prove this fact.

My problems are with $\tan(\frac{1}{x})$. As I understand, when $x \to 0$, $\tan(\frac{1}{x})$ is not defined, because $\tan(\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}$ and both the $\sin$ and the $\cos$ oscillate as they approach infinity, hence there is no definite value for them.

Maybe this problem requires an approach that I am not familiar with, but it appears as homework in a Calculus I course, so it should not involve super advanced maths techniques.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}$ with $\tan(1/x)$ looks very strange since $\tan(1/x)$ it is not defined in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @user657324 I know, yet Wolfram Alpha evaluates it to 1. Can it be a mistake by the software?

Comment: I think it's meant to use $x\sin x\to 0$ and $\cos x$ is limited. And $(1+x)^{1/x}\to e$, it follows $\to e^0 = 1$ .

Comment: I would explore the following: if the limit existed, by continuity of $e$, $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{tan(1/x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}exp(tan(1/x)log(1+x))=exp(\lim_{x\to 0}tan(1/x)log(1+x))$ and then try to work out $\lim_{x\to 0}tan(1/x)log(1+x)$ through L'hopital Rule by writing $\lim_{x\to 0}tan(1/x)log(1+x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{log(1+x)}{cos(1/x)/sin(1/x)}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit does not exist.

Note that there are arbitrarily large positive solutions to the equation $\tan \theta=\theta$ (sketch the graphs: tan regularly goes from $0$ to $+\infty$ and there is a solution in each such segment). For every solution, setting $x=1/\theta$ gives $(1+x)^{\tan(1/x)}=(1+1/\theta)^\theta\geq 2$.

This gives an infinite sequence approaching $0$ from above for which the function exceeds $2$; you can easily find a sequence for which the function takes the value $1$ (e.g. $x_n=1/(n\pi)$), so there is no limit.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. If this problem was in my exam, I would have answered exactly the same, but I was puzzled by Wolfram Alpha's solution. I'll report this issue to them, maybe they have a bug in their software.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$(1+x)^{\tan(\frac1{x})}=\left[\left(1+x\right)^\frac1x\right]^{x\tan \frac1x}$$

and the limit doesn’t exist indeed

- for $\frac1x=\pi n\implies x\tan \frac1x=0$
- for $\frac1x=\pi n+\arctan n \implies x\tan \frac1x\to \frac1 \pi$